# Google UI app: publishing two versions of the same code?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is this possible? I think I may have missed something obvious here. I have a live UI scripts app, and I need to fix a bug. The potential bugfix has to be tested on multiple browsers, so it actually has to be published, instead of just trying out the "current version". This means that it has to be published to a new URL.

Thanks.

Comment: not a app engine, question. I removed the tag

Answer (score 0):

*it actually has to be published, instead of just trying out the "current version"* ?

There is no reason why using different browsers should prevent from using de 'dev' version of an app... you can login in many browser at the same time and play with the dev version on each browser (I do that very often using a couple of android and osX browsers simultaneously). Did you try and did you meet issues doing so ?